# Generating statistics of data set in JSON in Angular

Tags: angular

consider I have a data set in JSON with columns employee_name,location,score
ex

```
 {"employees":[
{ "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "Location":"1" , "score":"10"},
{ "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "Location":"1", "score":"25" },
{ "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "Location":"2", "score":"10" }
]}
```

what is best way to generate statistics like
1. total number of locations in data set
2. average score of each location
3. lowest scoring employee etc.

Is there any built in library with Angular ?

Comment: I am looking for a library which can give me like complete statistical analysis   like finding minimum, maximum , average scores which also allows me to put some filters at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Mhmm no but Javascript has some nice methods like Array.map, Array.reduce, Array.filter.

Comment: I want to further use those statistics to plot graphs, I might have large amount of records at a time like 10000+ records

Answer (score 0):

```js
var json = {"employees":[
{ "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "Location":"1" , "score":"10"},
{ "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "Location":"1", "score":"25" },
{ "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "Location":"2", "score":"10" }
]};

let totalLocation = json.employees.
  map(function(item){ return item.Location; }).
  reduce(function(a, b){ return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b); }, 0);
console.log(totalLocation);

let averageScore = json.employees.
  map(function(item){ return item.score; }).
  reduce(function(a, b){ return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b); }, 0);
  
console.log(averageScore/json.employees.length);

let lowescoringEmployee = Math.min.apply(Math,json.employees.map(function(o){return o.score;}))

console.log(lowescoringEmployee);
```